# How to force specific type in C++ preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to generate a static variable via a preprocessor macro for logging purposes. The variable serves as a counter how often a specific message as been sent already. in order to make this thread-safe I wanted to switch from using an `int` counter to `std::atomic<int>` - which works fine on most compilers:

```cpp
#define GENERATE_LOG_VAR(Count) static std::atomic<int> local___FUNCTION__##Count##__LINE__ = std::atomic<int>(Count)
#define GET_LOG_VARIABLE(Count) local___FUNCTION__##Count##__LINE__
```

However, on GCC 7.3.1 I get the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'
 #define GENERATE_LOG_VAR(Count) static std::atomic<int> local___FUNCTION__##Count##__LINE__ = std::atomic<int>(Count)
                                                                                                                     ^
note: in expansion of macro 'GENERATE_LOG_VAR'
     GENERATE_LOG_VAR(max_log_count);                                                                                        \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: declared here
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~
```

So I understand that the compiler somehow interprets `Count` as `std::atomic<int>` and tries to call the copy constructor which seems to be deleted. But how can I circumvent this problem?

I have already tried simply assigning `Count` with very similar results:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'
 #define GENERATE_ONCE GENERATE_LOG_VAR(1)
                                      ^
note: in definition of macro 'GENERATE_LOG_VAR'
 #define GENERATE_LOG_VAR(Count) static std::atomic<int> local___FUNCTION__##Count##__LINE__ = Count
                                                                                                  ^~~~~
note: declared here
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~
note:   after user-defined conversion: constexpr std::atomic<int>::atomic(std::atomic<int>::__integral_type)
       constexpr atomic(__integral_type __i) noexcept : __base_type(__i) { }
                 ^~~~~~
```

So my question is either

- how can I force the compiler to interpret `Count` as `int`? or
- how can I solve this otherwise?

Comment: That code in theory performs a copy-construction from the instance on the RHS, but the copy-constructor is deleted, and C++ pre 17 requires that said copy ctor be callable, even if copy elision would mean it wouldn't be called in practice. You can avoid that via C++17 and guaranteed copy elision, or simply construct directly rather than from a different instance on the RHS, by using braces or parentheses instead of assignment style initialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your macro to be

```
#define GENERATE_LOG_VAR(Count) static std::atomic<int> local___FUNCTION__##Count##__LINE__(Count)
```

This will avoid constructing a copy, or trying to construct a copy, or whatever the precise standardese says in this situation.

Comment: No code ever "directly calls the constructor". Syntax does not exist to do that. This is a defining declaration with an initialiser. An invocation of the constructor is just one part of the sequence of steps that makes up object creation, and it's done for you by the language itself.

Comment: Good luck explaining `new(int_address) int(0)` to someone.

Comment: I've done so, successfully, numerous times. It's not "pedanticism" - understanding that C++ is an abstraction with a concept of object lifetimes that goes way beyond the programmer typing "calls to the constructor" is actually really important. The standard specifically states that the constructor has no name. It is not a function, and you never call it. Period.

Comment: Isn't there a [tag:language-lawyer] for that kind of pedantic behavior?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings If I write a piece of C++ code whose effect is that the constructor is called, am I not entitled to say "I've called the constructor"? In a more ... informal way of course.

Comment: @bolov Perhaps, if you're loosely and informally describing to your friends and colleagues what you did today, not teaching people how C++ works on a site dedicated to sharing facts and knowledge. :)

Comment: Answer looks much better now

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings some food for thought: there is a reason why the standard isn't a good teaching tool. When you teach you need to make some simplifications, omit some things and even tell some "lies". And even beyond teaching, nobody uses the standard rigid formal wording in normal life. That doesn't mean that the pedantic, standard analysis doesn't have its place.